# Error In Insert Method for Ordered Array

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement, break

I made an ordered array and I have an insert method created. Everything seems to be good with the code besides the error I am getting on a `break`statement. On my break statement I am getting an error "Syntax error on this token ';',Expression expected after this token. Is there something I'm missing about the `break` statement? Any ideas are appreciated, thanks!

```
 public boolean insert(IndexRecord newValue)
{
    int j;
    if (nextElem==maxSize) return false;

    for(j=nextElem-1;j>=0;j--)
    {
        if ((IdxRec[j].compareTo(newValue)<0)) break;
        [j+1]=IdxRec[j];

    }
    IdxRec[j+1]=newValue;
    nextElem++;
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. On the next line,

```
[j+1]=IdxRec[j];
```

should be

```
IdxRec[j+1] = IdxRec[j];
```

Comment: Duhhh. Thanks. I would think after coding for 2 years I could figure that out ;p